# Vbscript webdav folder create

Tags: vbscript, directory, webdav

I'm trying to create folder by Vbscript.

I'm noob to Vbscript.

Can not undersand why this code returns: The folder has not been created. Status is Unsupported Media Type.

I took it here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/03/12/howto-vb-an-example-to-create-a-public-folder-with-storage-limit-settings.aspx

Code [Vbscript]:

```
cmdMakeFolder_Click

Private Sub cmdMakeFolder_Click()
    Dim XMLreq
    Set XMLreq = createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
    Dim sReq
    Dim parsePhone
    Dim sSourceURL

    sSourceURL = "https://shkur.webdav.hidrive.strato.com/users/shkur/"
    ' Note: This URL is broken down as:
    '     myexserver is the Exchange box name
    '     MYDOM.EXTEST.MYCOMP.COM  is the full domain name the Exchange box is in.
    '     Exadmin/admin is a special designation giving the login user higher level privs.
    ' Exchange explorer may/may not need the %20 in PUBLIC%20FOLDERS
    ' The account you use to log in with Must have full blown Exchange admin privs and be 
    ' a domain acct.

    'XMLreq.open "MKCOL", sSourceURL, False, "Administrator", "Pxxxx" 
          ' If the Exchange is the DC, you probably dont have to specify the DC to login
    XMLreq.open "MKCOL", sSourceURL, False, "login", "password" 
          ' Here Exchange box is not the DC

    XMLreq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"

    sReq = "<?xml version='1.0'?>"
    sReq = sReq & "<a:propertyupdate xmlns:a='DAV:' xmlns:e='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/' " & _
                    "xmlns:p='http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/'>"
    sReq = sReq & "<a:set><a:prop>" & vbCrLf
    sReq = sReq & "<e:outlookfolderclass>IPF.Folder</e:outlookfolderclass>" & vbCrLf    
          ' Folder class for outlook
    sReq = sReq & "<a:contentclass>urn:content-classes:folder</a:contentclass>" & vbCrLf  
          ' Folder content class
    sReq = sReq & "<a:isreadonly>1</a:isreadonly>" & vbCrLf  ' Read only
    sReq = sReq & "<a:ishidden>1</a:ishidden>" & vbCrLf       ' Hidden

     sReq = sReq & "<p:x67790003>1</p:x67790003>" & vbCrLf 
          'Use the quotas specified by other properties.
     sReq = sReq & "<e:storagequotaissuewarninglimit>200</e:storagequotaissuewarninglimit>" & vbCrLf 
          'Issue warning at (Kb).
     sReq = sReq & "<p:x67210003>1</p:x67210003>" & vbCrLf  'Prohibit post at (Kb).
     sReq = sReq & "<p:x67220003>1</p:x67220003>" & vbCrLf  'Maximum item size (Kb).

    sReq = sReq & "<e:addressbookdisplayname>qwe</e:addressbookdisplayname>" & vbCrLf

    sReq = sReq & "</a:prop></a:set></a:propertyupdate>"

    XMLreq.send sReq
    'Debug.Print "xmlReq.Status = " & XMLreq.Status
    If XMLreq.Status = "201" Or XMLreq.Status = "207" Then
        MsgBox "The folder has been created.  Status is " & XMLreq.statusText, vbCritical, "Folder Created!!"
    Else
        ' Note: Error 405 can mean permissions problem on item already exists.
        MsgBox "The folder has not been created.  Status is " & XMLreq.statusText, vbCritical, " Folder not Created!!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

That response status (415 - Unsupported Media Type) means that the server has rejected the request entity. In your request the request entity is the XML. Note that a 'normal' MKCOL request does not use XML in the body, only extended MKCOL does, which is not implmented on all servers.

So its most likely just that the webdav server that you're using does not support extended MKCOL

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-vcarddav-webdav-mkcol-06

Answer (score 0):

отвечаю сам себе вот так работает!

```
    cmdMakeFolder_Click

Private Sub cmdMakeFolder_Click()
    Dim XMLreq
    Set XMLreq = createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
    'Set XMLreq = createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0")
    Dim sReq
    Dim parsePhone
    Dim sSourceURL

    sSourceURL = "https://shkur.webdav.hidrive.strato.com/users/shkur/qweer/"
    ' Note: This URL is broken down as:
    '     myexserver is the Exchange box name
    '     MYDOM.EXTEST.MYCOMP.COM  is the full domain name the Exchange box is in.
    '     Exadmin/admin is a special designation giving the login user higher level privs.
    ' Exchange explorer may/may not need the %20 in PUBLIC%20FOLDERS
    ' The account you use to log in with Must have full blown Exchange admin privs and be 
    ' a domain acct.

    'XMLreq.open "MKCOL", sSourceURL, False, "Administrator", "Pxxxx" 
          ' If the Exchange is the DC, you probably dont have to specify the DC to login
    XMLreq.open "MKCOL", sSourceURL, False, "login", "password" 
          ' Here Exchange box is not the DC

    XMLreq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"

    'sReq = "<?xml version='1.0'?><a:propertyupdate xmlns:a='DAV:' xmlns:e='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/' xmlns:p='http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/'><a:set><a:prop><e:outlookfolderclass>IPF.Folder</e:outlookfolderclass><a:contentclass>urn:content-classes:folder</a:contentclass><a:isreadonly>1</a:isreadonly><a:ishidden>1</a:ishidden><p:x67790003>1</p:x67790003><e:storagequotaissuewarninglimit>200</e:storagequotaissuewarninglimit><p:x67210003>1</p:x67210003><p:x67220003>1</p:x67220003><e:addressbookdisplayname>qwe</e:addressbookdisplayname></a:prop></a:set></a:propertyupdate>"

    XMLreq.send sReq
    'Debug.Print "xmlReq.Status = " & XMLreq.Status
    If XMLreq.Status = "201" Or XMLreq.Status = "207" Then
        MsgBox "The folder has been created.  Status is " & XMLreq.statusText, vbCritical, "Folder Created!!"
    Else
        ' Note: Error 405 can mean permissions problem on item already exists.
        MsgBox "The folder has not been created.  Status is " & XMLreq.statusText, vbCritical, " Folder not Created!!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to use a non-standard extension of MKCOL (Microsoft-specific) with a server that does not understand it.